# Retrieving just the item value from a dynamodb table?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm playing around with dynamodb and set up a very simple table of 5 items, each with 2 attributes (userId, name). I'm then accessing this through java and outputting the items to the terminal. The relevant code is

```
ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest(tableName);
ScanResult scanResult = dynamoDB.scan(scanRequest);
System.out.println("There are " + scanResult.getCount() + " items in this table\n");
System.out.println(scanResult.getItems().get(0).get("userId"));
```

The terminal output is

```
There are 5 items in this table

{N: 3, }
```

I just want to get the '3', i.e. just the value as opposed to the value AND the type. I know this is elementary but I'm not getting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve the relevant [AttributeValue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) property.  In this case your AttributeValue is a number {N, 3}, so you would use

```
scanResult.getItems().get(0).get("userId").getN()
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something annoyingly simple! Thanks a million for answering so quickly and helping me out!

Comment: Robocode, as common courtesy, if you're pleased with the answer, mark Zim-Zam's post as answered, thank you.

Comment: Hi BlackBox, I tried but was informed I had to wait 5 minutes before I could