# dynamodb getitem using php - I only want to retrieve the value

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm able to query my dynamodb tables, but I only want to retrieve the actual value.  I don't want the formatting output.  This same question has been answered here for Java, but I'm looking for the PHP solution:
[Retrieving just the item value from a dynamodb table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903569/retrieving-just-the-item-value-from-a-dynamodb-table)

Here is my getitem query:

```
$response = $dynamodb->getItem(array(
    "TableName" => $tableName,
    "ConsistentRead" => true,
    "Key" => array(
        "userguid" => array(Type::STRING => $userguid)
    ),
    "AttributesToGet" => array("token")
));
print_r($response["Item"]["token"]);
```

Here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [S] => 9d194513
)
```

All I want to get back is:

```
9d194513
```

I assumed the logical answer would be to change the last line to:

```
print_r($response["Item"]["token"]["S"]);
```

But then my code doesn't return anything at all.  Obviously still learning PHP here, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var_dump($response);` can you post what it prints?

Comment: a plain old `var_dump($response);` returns 8098 lines.  I assumed your just looking for the output of `var_dump($response["Item"]["token"]);`.  This returns: `array(1) {
  ["S"]=>
  string(8) "9d194513"
}
`

Comment: Yes i saw on question, try with `echo $response["Item"]["token"]["S"];` or `print($response["Item"]["token"]["S"]);` as it is not an array

Comment: Fabio- you nailed it sir.  The answer was `echo $response["Item"]["token"]["S"];`.
Thanks a ton!

Comment: When I query DynamoDB from zend for the first time, it takes around 3 seconds. and then it takes less than a second to execute other query. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Where on earth is Type::STRING buried - I want it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `print_r` function, just either `echo` your variables

```
echo $response["Item"]["token"]["S"];
```

or store in a variable for later use

```
$res_token = $response["Item"]["token"]["S"];
```

Comment: @Geek: From the documentation: "print_r() displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans." and "echo outputs one or more strings.".

Comment: Is there a way to get a simple Key:Value pair response from DynamoDb with AWS SDK ? without data Types

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `getPath` convenience method built into the `Model` object that the SDK returns for operations.

```
echo $response->getPath('Item/token/S');
```

For more information about working with responses in the SDK, see the [Response Models](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/feature-models.html) page in the [AWS SDK for PHP User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

Though it's an old question but for anyone coming to this page for seeking answer, this is how I have done it.

`getItem` returns a `Result`object. You can call the `get()` function of the SDK, which will give you an array containing the exact value.

```
$params = [
        "TableName" => "EpgApiAccessCount",
        "Key" => $this->marshalJson('
            {
                "ApiUserKey": "' . $apiUserkey . '"
            }
        ')
    ];

    $result = $this->client->getitem($params);
    if (!$result instanceof ResultInterface) {
        return 0;
    }


    $item = $this->unmarshalItem($result->get("Item"));
    return $item["AccessCount"];
```

Of course your value and table name will be different, and you can print or do anything else with the value.